# Extract rtrend output to list with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a bit of code I used to extract regression output to a list that I could copy out of the console and paste somewhere that works beautifully on 1052 records of 33 weather stations each with 18-33 years worth of data by station ID. Without really understanding how, I made it work. Now trying to modify it for the same purpose with rtrends::mkTrend which outputs a list of seven parameters.

dat_sample:

```
 x   y grp
1990 188 CDO
1991 164 CDO
1992 159 CDO
1993 219 CDO
1994 202 CDO
1995 249 CDO
1996 243 CDO
1997 220 CDO
1998 186 CDO
1999 187 CDO
1990 188 Key
1991 207 Key
1992 211 Key
1993 183 Key
1994 171 Key
1995 215 Key
1996 184 Key
1997 202 Key
1998 186 Key
1999 168 Key
```

The accursed code:

```
dat_sample[, list(p.value=mkTrend(y)[2],
     p_val_corr=mkTrend(y)[4],
     tau=mkTrend(y)[5],
     Sens=mkTrend(y)[7],
     by=format(grp,justify = "r"))]
```

The desired output:

```
       p.value   p_val_corr         tau   Sens   by
 1:  0.5915050     0.591505   0.1555556      4  CDO
 2:  0.3710934    0.3710934  -0.2444444   -1.8  Key
```

The actual output

```
      p.value p_val_corr        tau Sens  by
 1: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 2: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 3: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 4: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 5: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 6: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 7: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 8: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
 9: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
10: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 CDO
11: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
12: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
13: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
14: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
15: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
16: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
17: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
18: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
19: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
20: 0.3981742  0.3981742 -0.1421053 -0.6 Key
```

Comment: I would try executing mkTrend outside of the data object and then assemble the results. Either that or don’t include the by parameter in the result list.

Comment: `rtrend` or `rtrends`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front:

- You get all the same numbers because your `by=` is *inside* your `list(.)`, so data.table is not doing any grouping, the analysis is on all data combined. The reason you get 20 rows is because the `by=format(grp,justify="right")` is returning a vector of length 20, the number of rows in the original frame.
- Instead of multiple calls, we can do one call and use `as.list(.)` instead of `list(.)` here. This is equivalent to calling it four times for the values you want, but 4x quicker :-)

---

I don't have fftw installed so I can't try `rtrend::mkTrend(.)`, but I can use [`mkTrend_r`](https://github.com/rpkgs/rtrend/blob/master/R/mkTrend_r.R) (and [`slope_sen_r`](https://github.com/rpkgs/rtrend/blob/master/R/slope.R)).

By itself, `mkTrend_r` returns a vector, and `data.table` happily assumes it should be in "long" format:

```r
dat_sample[, mkTrend_r(y), by="grp"]
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
#        grp          V1
#     <char>       <num>
#  1:    CDO   0.5366563
#  2:    CDO   0.5915050
#  3:    CDO   0.5366563
#  4:    CDO   0.5915050
#  5:    CDO   3.1428571
#  6:    CDO 184.4142857
#  7:    Key  -0.8944272
#  8:    Key   0.3710934
#  9:    Key  -0.8944272
# 10:    Key   0.3710934
# 11:    Key  -1.8000000
# 12:    Key 201.4000000
```

We can fix that with `as.list`:

```r
dat_sample[, as.list(mkTrend_r(y)), by="grp"]
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
#       grp         z0     pval0          z      pval       slp intercept
#    <char>      <num>     <num>      <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>
# 1:    CDO  0.5366563 0.5915050  0.5366563 0.5915050  3.142857  184.4143
# 2:    Key -0.8944272 0.3710934 -0.8944272 0.3710934 -1.800000  201.4000
```

And since you want only a few columns, we can subset:

```r
dat_sample[, as.list(mkTrend_r(y)[c("pval0", "pval", "z", "slp")]), by="grp"]
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
# Warning in lm(y ~ I(1:n))$resid :
#   partial match of 'resid' to 'residuals'
#       grp     pval0      pval          z       slp
#    <char>     <num>     <num>      <num>     <num>
# 1:    CDO 0.5915050 0.5915050  0.5366563  3.142857
# 2:    Key 0.3710934 0.3710934 -0.8944272 -1.800000
```

And you can rename by either adding `c("p.value", "p_val_corr", ...) :=` to the left of `as.list`, or you can use `setnames` after that full expression.

I don't know offhand which value is `tau`, either `z` or `z0`?

BTW: I think that package might need some attention: the warnings are because of abbreviated column names in the code (R lets us be lazy), and the documentations says the returned value names are `Z` and `Z0`, not `z` and `z0`. Minor certainly, but makes me wonder ...

Comment: Thank you r2evans! That solves it. I knew it had to be a simple fix :)